# How can i remove content and give background in table

Tags: javascript, css

So, i want to achieve this

[image]

Here is what i do so far

```
$('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
                var tr = $(this);
                var th = tr.find('td:first-child').attr('class');
                var td = tr.find('td').attr('class');

                //the match box will be red, only the the td of row

                if (th == td) {
                    //important background red

                    tr.find('td').attr('style', 'background-color: red !important');

                }

            });
```

with my script above, i can't achieve the result. Here is the result

[image]

Here is my table in html

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-auto text-center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th class="COL1">COL1</th>
      <th class="COL2">COL2</th>
      <th class="COL3">COL3</th>
      <th class="COL4">COL4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="COL1">COL1</td>
      <td>0 %</td>
      <td>13.5 %</td>
      <td>18.9 %</td>
      <td>5.4 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="COL2">COL2</td>
      <td>29.7 %</td>
      <td>0 %</td>
      <td>2.7 %</td>
      <td>0 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="COL3">COL3</td>
      <td>18.9 %</td>
      <td>8.1 %</td>
      <td>0 %</td>
      <td>2.7 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="COL4">COL4</td>
      <td>0 %</td>
      <td>0 %</td>
      <td>0 %</td>
      <td>0 %</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So how can i achieve it ? thanks in advance

Comment: Either there would be conditional checks (`if (something === another) { // add blue background }`) or CSS. Have you tried either of those?

Answer (score 0):

#### Iterate the nodelist and check its index

Given a table cell of row index `i` and column index `j`, you'd like to change the cell background to red if `i===j`, correct?

In the snippet below, I did:

1. Select all table rows (i.e. `tr`)
2. Iterate each table row, and select all of its child cells (i.e. `td`)
3. Change the background color of the `td` cell of `i`th index to red.

No HTML markup has been changed, but a few simple CSS lines are added just to make it a bit nicer. This should work even if the table's column and row counts change.

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
rows.forEach((row, i) => {
  const children = row.querySelectorAll('td');
  return i === 0 ? null : children[i].style.background = "red";
});
```

```css
th, td {
  padding: 10px;
}

th, td:first-of-type {
  background: #ddf;
}
td {
  background: #eee;
}
td:first-of-type {
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-auto text-center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th class="COL1">COL1</th>
      <th class="COL2">COL2</th>
      <th class="COL3">COL3</th>
      <th class="COL4">COL4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="COL1">COL1</td>
      <td>0 %</td>
      <td>13.5 %</td>
      <td>18.9 %</td>
      <td>5.4 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="COL2">COL2</td>
      <td>29.7 %</td>
      <td>0 %</td>
      <td>2.7 %</td>
      <td>0 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="COL3">COL3</td>
      <td>18.9 %</td>
      <td>8.1 %</td>
      <td>0 %</td>
      <td>2.7 %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="COL4">COL4</td>
      <td>0 %</td>
      <td>0 %</td>
      <td>0 %</td>
      <td>0 %</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```